# Reasoning for union type to fail to allow property look up

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, tsc

**This has mystified me for a long time:**

[image]

Basically the situation is:

```
interface NLUAddOpts{}
interface NLURunOpts{
  treeify: boolean
}

const fn = function(opts: NLUAddOpts | NLURunOpts){
  if(opts.treeify){  // compilation error

  }
}
```

**Why**!? If you are just reading a property, but not a subproperty of that property, then shouldn't it just compile? At least it should compile if it's in an if-check.

On the other hand, if it was an assignment:

```
const treeify = opts.treeify;
```

I guess I could see why it wouldn't compile.

What's the best way to solve this one?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is pretty simple, you have stated that `opts` has a type `NLUAddOpts` OR `NLURunOpts`. This means you can only access properties that are common to both types otherwise TS has no way of knowing if the property actually exists.

Now, if a `NLURunOpts` will *always* have the property `treeify` and `NLUAddOpts` will *never* have it then you can do the following:

```
if ('treeify' in opts) {
    // opts is now of 'NLURunOpts' type
}
```

You could also define a type guard:

```
function isRunOpts(opts: any): opts is NLURunOpts {
    return opts.treeify !== undefined;
}

if (isRunOpts(opts)) {
    // opts is now of 'NLURunOpts' type
}
```

Otherwise you could do the following:

```
if((opts as NLURunOpts).treeify) {

}
```

Which asserts that `opts` is of type `NLURunOpts`